# Block List Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in one of my views:

```
<% @videos.each do |i| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle("even","odd") %>">
      <td><%= i.title %></td>
      <td><%= i.premiere %></td>
      <td><%= i.film_type %></td>
      <td><%= i.preferred_date %></td>
      <td><%= i.actual_date %></td>
      <td><%= i.created_at %></td>
      <td><%= i.updated_at %></td>
      <td><%= i.size %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

It is listing all of the items in a table (which is then sortable) from each video. I want to make the title link to the video that the title belongs to. Could someone please show me how to make i.title into a link? I tried lots of formats and none of them seem to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link to Rails' standard "show" action for the video:

```
<td><%= link_to(i.title, video_path(i)) %></td>
```

This assumes that `i.class == Video` and you have `map.resources :videos` in your routes.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I knew it would be simple but I couldn't find a simple explanation. Thank you very much!